# When using JPA, 2 entry are added to the data base instead of just one

Tags: java, database, jpa

In the service class, I am adding data to 2 tables from one form submission, it adds the data to the Breweries table fine but when the data goes to the Brewerie_Geocodes table, it duplicates the row. I think my code is pretty logical but I must be forgetting something.

the method in the service class is

```
public void addAnBreweries(Breweries brewerie) {
    EntityManager em = DBUtil.getEMF().createEntityManager();
    EntityTransaction trans = em.getTransaction();
    Date date = new Date();
    brewerie.setLastMod(date);
    try {
        trans.begin();
        em.persist(brewerie);
        trans.commit();

        BreweriesGeocode bg = new BreweriesGeocode();
        bg.setBreweryId((Integer) brewerie.getId());
        bg.setLongitude((float)brewerie.getLongitude());
        bg.setLatitude((float)brewerie.getLatitude());
         trans.begin();
        em.persist(bg);
        trans.commit();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
}
```

the data that I am getting in the table is 
[image]

the code for the Breweries is

@Entity

```
 @Table(name = "breweries")
    @SecondaryTable(name = "breweries_geocode")

    @XmlRootElement
    @NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findById", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.id = :id"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByName", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.name = :name"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByAddress1", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.address1 = :address1"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByAddress2", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.address2 = :address2"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByCity", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.city = :city"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByState", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.state = :state"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByCode", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.code = :code"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByCountry", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.country = :country"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByPhone", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.phone = :phone"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByWebsite", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.website = :website"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByImage", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.image = :image"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByAddUser", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.addUser = :addUser"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByLastMod", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.lastMod = :lastMod"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByCreditLimit", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.creditLimit = :creditLimit"),
        @NamedQuery(name = "Breweries.findByEmail", query = "SELECT b FROM Breweries b WHERE b.email = :email")})
    public class Breweries implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
private Integer id;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "address1")
private String address1;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "address2")
private String address2;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "city")
private String city;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 255)
@Column(name = "state")
private String state;
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 25)
@Column(name = "code")
private String code;
@Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "country")
    private String country;
    // @Pattern(regexp="^\\(?(\\d{3})\\)?[- ]?(\\d{3})[- ]?(\\d{4})$", message="Invalid phone/fax format, should be as xxx-xxx-xxxx")//if the field contains phone or fax number consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "phone")
    private String phone;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "website")
    private String website;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 255)
    @Column(name = "image")
    private String image;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Lob
    @Size(min = 1, max = 65535)
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "add_user")
    private int addUser;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "last_mod")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date lastMod;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "credit_limit")
    private double creditLimit;
    // @Pattern(regexp="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?", message="Invalid email")//if the field contains email address consider using this annotation to enforce field validation
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 1, max = 50)
    @Column(name = "email")
    private String email;
    @Column(table = "breweries_geocode")
    private float latitude;
    @Column(table = "breweries_geocode")
    private float longitude;

    public float getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(float latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public float getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(float longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Breweries() {
    }

    public Breweries(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Breweries(Integer id, String name, String address1, String address2, String city, String state, String code, String country, String phone, String website, String image, String description, int addUser, Date lastMod, double creditLimit, String email) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.address1 = address1;
        this.address2 = address2;
        this.city = city;
        this.state = state;
        this.code = code;
        this.country = country;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.website = website;
        this.image = image;
        this.description = description;
        this.addUser = addUser;
        this.lastMod = lastMod;
        this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAddress1() {
        return address1;
    }

    public void setAddress1(String address1) {
        this.address1 = address1;
    }

    public String getAddress2() {
        return address2;
    }

    public void setAddress2(String address2) {
        this.address2 = address2;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return city;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getAddUser() {
        return addUser;
    }

    public void setAddUser(int addUser) {
        this.addUser = addUser;
    }

    public Date getLastMod() {
        return lastMod;
    }

    public void setLastMod(Date lastMod) {
        this.lastMod = lastMod;
    }

    public double getCreditLimit() {
        return creditLimit;
    }

    public void setCreditLimit(double creditLimit) {
        this.creditLimit = creditLimit;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 0;
        hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object object) {
        // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
        if (!(object instanceof Breweries)) {
            return false;
        }
        Breweries other = (Breweries) object;
        if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "lit.sd4.model.Breweries[ id=" + id + " ]";
    }
```

}

the code for BreweriesGeocode is

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "breweries_geocode")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "BreweriesGeocode.findAll", query = "SELECT b FROM BreweriesGeocode b"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BreweriesGeocode.findById", query = "SELECT b FROM BreweriesGeocode b WHERE b.id = :id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BreweriesGeocode.findByBreweryId", query = "SELECT b FROM BreweriesGeocode b WHERE b.breweryId = :breweryId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BreweriesGeocode.findByLatitude", query = "SELECT b FROM BreweriesGeocode b WHERE b.latitude = :latitude"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "BreweriesGeocode.findByLongitude", query = "SELECT b FROM BreweriesGeocode b WHERE b.longitude = :longitude")})
public class BreweriesGeocode implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "brewery_id")
    private int breweryId;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "latitude")
    private float latitude;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "longitude")
    private float longitude;

    public BreweriesGeocode() {
    }

    public BreweriesGeocode(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public BreweriesGeocode(Integer id, int breweryId, float latitude, float longitude) {
        this.id = id;
        this.breweryId = breweryId;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public int getBreweryId() {
        return breweryId;
    }

    public void setBreweryId(int breweryId) {
        this.breweryId = breweryId;
    }

    public float getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(float latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public float getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }
public void setLongitude(float longitude) {
    this.longitude = longitude;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 0;
    hash += (id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0);
    return hash;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object object) {
    // TODO: Warning - this method won't work in the case the id fields are not set
    if (!(object instanceof BreweriesGeocode)) {
        return false;
    }
    BreweriesGeocode other = (BreweriesGeocode) object;
    if ((this.id == null && other.id != null) || (this.id != null && !this.id.equals(other.id))) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for BreweriesCeocode and Breweries? I'm getting the idea that you're doing a OneToOne or OneToMany behind the scenes.

Comment: @Jason I have added the two classes you have asked, there is no relationship between the tables in the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first class `Breweries` you already define a secondary table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "breweries")
  @SecondaryTable(name = "breweries_geocode")
public class Breweries { ... }
```

Then later in your class you're stating that some fields will be stored into the secondary table, as shown at these lines:

```
@Column(table = "breweries_geocode")
private float latitude;
@Column(table = "breweries_geocode")
private float longitude;
```

But you declare another class `BreweriesGeocode` also as an Entity associated to a table:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "breweries_geocode")
public class BreweriesGeocode { ... }
```

By doing that the EntityManager and JPA2 implementation will assume there are two very different entities. Therefore calling the first persist() will already generate a record in the `breweries_geocode` table and the second one will also persist a (brand-new) entity to the same table.

I think a valid simple example is well explained here: [JPA SecondaryTable Annotation](http://www.thejavageek.com/2014/09/18/jpa-secondarytable-annotation-example/)
To make it better you may start by removing the @Entity annotation from the other class or use it as a Delegate. You could also tell the EntityManager (but its a different topic) to retrieve the previously handled entity and update its state (context-based with some caching, etc). In the latest case it would recognize that its the same entity for example and not persist a new one but just update it.